# How to remove UIWebView component completely in current project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

when submitting my latest build, Apple has a response with this warning.

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more
>   information.

Fyi,

1. I already migrate all UIWebView component to the WKWebView component in my project based on Apple recommendation.
2. I tried `grep -r UIWebView .` and `grep -r UIWebView /Path/To/Project/*` to cleared all UIWeview in Project.

but Apple still response with the same warning.

Is there any ways to search for any UIWebView element that still attached to my project? Kindly suggest.

Comment: You can search for `UIWebView` in project using find navigator and it will show all the places where UIWebView is used and replace it with `WKWebvView` implementation.

Comment: You need to update all third party frameworks like facebook, google, etc.

Comment: You need to update all librairies ! try to use last versions of your librairies and frameworks.

Comment: @skety777 Thank you

I added some frameworks from another folder path, it's not included in the Project folder path.

When I try to grep -r UIWebView . only within the project directory

So it does not show an error, try this terminal command in every folder path that included in your project

Comment: hi there , how can I remove framework ?

Comment: Was this issue resolved? Because I need some help on the same topic too.

Comment: yes, resolved
use terminal and try to grep -r UIWebView . in all within a project directory, added frameworks/pods and any files/framework added from external folder path

Answer (score 0):

Remove UniWebView package reference from Manifest file
and also update unity ads to latest version