# Safely remove UIWebView from ionic project + support iOS 10

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview

I'm working on an ionic project which is using `Cordova` and several plugins.

According to Apple, we won't be able to submit app updates soon as we are currently getting a warning saying we are using `UIWebview` inside our app:

> The App Store will no longer accept new apps using `UIWebView` as of April 2020 and app updates using `UIWebView` as of December 2020.

I've made a lot of researches to find out what's the concrete solution but nothing seems clear.
Some people say Apple just detects if the whole project contains the string and some others say they only detect if an object is declared,.. Anyway, I've seen `Cordova` itself contains some `UIWebView` (Cordova 9.0.0 - Cordova-lib@9.0.1).

- Has someone be able to submit an app to App store Connect without getting the warning?
- is the project containing commented `UIWebview` elements?
- Is it safe to just replace `UIWebView` by `WKWebView` and only that?
- Is it possible to get a `Cordova` version without `UIWebview`?

I'm also experiencing another issue related to iOS 10. 
To support iOS 10 we must use `cordova-plugin-webview` 2.5.1 or less. (iOS 10 is ok but the css is a bit broken in my whole app). The problem is it is recommended to update this plugin to 4.X cause of the `UIWebview`.

- Then I'm wondering if someone is able to support iOS 10 without getting the `UIWebview` error and how?

Here's some configurations I've set: 
    - cordova-plugin-webview v4.1.3,
    - cordova-plugin-inappbrowser v3.2.0,
    - cordova-ios 5.1.1 
    - wkwebviewonly to true in config.xml

Here some interesting links I've found:

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/418

[How to remove UIWebView component completely in current project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59169309/how-to-remove-uiwebview-component-completely-in-current-project)

https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/

Let me know if you need more information about my environment.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not just a text search. UIWebView appears in my app in quiet a few different places. For example it's in the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin which is suggested as a fix for this issue. It's painful trying to track down what is specifically causing it in your app. I couldn't find a way other than submitting the app to Testflight over and over having made modifications. For me it turned out to be capacitor-twitter that loads it. Omitting this, the app was accepted without warning.

My advice is to run

> grep -iRl uiwebview . > uiwebview.instances

and then use uiwebview.instances as a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Am using an IDE (Webstorm) and I did a text search for UIWebview in node_modules folder. It was easier to find the plugins that uses it. You can easily identify & skip the places where the text appears in comments.
In my case I found this plugin using the UIWebview:

- com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions and replaced it with cordova-plugin-nativepagetransitions